# Download different version of grep in cygwin?

Tags: macos, bash, grep, cygwin, setup.exe

I'd like to download a different version of grep in Cygwin. Currently, I have version 2.21, but I'd like to get version 2.5.1 (this is what runs on Mac OS by default, and I'm more familiar with that).

I obviously don't want to run the entire setup again.  Is  there a way to get the Mac OS version (i.e. 2.5.1)  without running setup all over again?  Thanks. <3

Comment: I think you *do* just run the setup again. It keeps track of what you've already installed and will show you a list. I think you click on the version number to cycle it through versions. Then click "install" (or whatever).

Comment: It doesn't look like cygwin has anything above 2.21 available. It has 2.21-1 and 2.21-2. (Look under Base.)

Comment: You can *always* compile your own version (`grep` does not have many dependencies, and the exercise is educational).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling is always a possible choice: `grep` lives here: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/, and given the tarball (ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/grep-2.5.1.tar.gz),

```
tar xf 2.5.1.tar.gz
cd 2.5.1
./configure
make && make install
```

(this will probably install into `/usr/local/bin` — you should read the instructions, e.g., the `--prefix` option to suit your own needs).

That assumes you are developing, and have installed `gcc` (the Cygwin setup program helps in that case).